# Why MultiThreading is not efficient in my code?

Tags: python, multithreading, file-upload, python-multithreading

So my code gets file names from filenames.txt and then sends a request with a file and gets the response.

For some reasons it uploads it multiple times for a single file and i can't understand why.

```
f = open('filenames.txt','r')
results = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
def makerequest(files):
    for filename in results:
        files = {'file': open(filename, 'rb')}
        url = 'https://www.google.com/'
        r = requests.post(url,headers=headers2,files=files,cookies=cookies1)
        print(r.text)
processes = []
pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(10)
pool.map(makerequest, results)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I want each thread to send a request with different filename e.g

Thread 1 uploads the file 1.txt

Thread 2 uploads the file 2.txt

Comment: Hi, the function is iterating over all the `results`. Perhaps have the for loop iterate over just the files that were passed in as the argument.

Comment: Still the same for some reasons,maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: Ya, you have each process doing all the requests, so you're doing 10x as much work as you need to be doing, but spread over 10 processes. Cut the results up and give individual "jobs" to each process. Also note, this is a case where multithreading can actually be used to some benefit. Multithreading can be easier to deal with than multiprocessing sometimes.

Comment: Can you help me to do that please? or with multithreading i spent a day about researching multiprocessing/threading but i couldn't find anything that can fix my issue or to recode it.

Comment: you get filename as `def makerequest(files):` but you don't use this `files` but you  use `for`- loop to work with all all filename - remove `for`-;loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send single filename as argument in `def makerequest(files):` but you never use it but you use `for`-loop to work with all filenames in every process. You have to remove `for`-loop.

```
def makerequest(filename):
    files = {'file': open(filename, 'rb')}
    url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers2, files=files, cookies=cookies1)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, you explained it well and also showed the code it is the best thing for a beginner like me to understand what went wrong and how to fix it.